# Get type parameters of property type using roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'd like to determine the type parameter of a property represented as an `IPropertySymbol` with a generic type. More precisely, I'd like to know if a property is of type int or int?. `property.Type.OriginalDefinition` gives me that it is a `System.Nullable<T>` but I'd like to know if it is a `Nullable<int>` or something else. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`TypeArguments` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.inamedtypesymbol.typearguments?view=roslyn-dotnet), which gives you exactly that.

Note that if the property is declared as `Nullable<T>` on a class with a generic type parameter, that will only give you a concrete type if your property symbol comes from a closed type (eg, `SomeClass<int>` rather than the `SomeClass<>` definition).

Comment: I had to cast`ITypeSymbol` to `INamedTypeSymbol` and now I have `TypeArguments` thanks. However, `propertyType.TypeArguments.First().Name` gives me "T". The property is declared as `public int? Property { get; set; }` and it's inside a non generic class. Any ideas?

Comment: @Peter: That would happen if you used `.OriginalDefinition`, which returns the open generic type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, for some reason I used `property.Type.OriginalDefinition` to get `propertyType`. Using `property.Type.TypeArguments.First()` now gives me `System.Int32` as expected.